# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in recursive function call

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I keep getting a segmentation fault error. The recursive function call is the problem. However, I can't solve it!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarysearch(int a[],int l,int x,int y){
  if(x>=l)
  {
    int mid= 1 + (x-1)/2;
    if(a[mid]==y) return mid;
    if(a[mid] > y) {return binarysearch(a, l, mid-1, y);}
    else{return binarysearch(a, mid+1, x, y);}
  }
  return -1;
}

void main()
{
  int a[]={2,3,4};
  int x=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  int y=2;
  int result =binarysearch(a,0,x-1,y);
  (result==-1)?printf("the number is not present in the array"):
               printf("the number is present at index%d",result);
}
```

Comment: `1 + (x-1)/2;` typo as `l + (x-l)/2;` ?

Comment: never use l as a variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `binarysearch()`, the line

```
int mid= 1 + (x-1)/2;
```

may be made

```
int mid=(x+l)/2;
```

ie, `mid` will be the integer division by `2` of the sum of the lowest and greatest indices of the part of the array currently under consideration.

Comment: the font of the website was confusing i mixed l for 1, ur solution worked